# Telerik RadMap Change Dynamically Generated Inline Styles

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, telerik

We have a web app that uses the Telerik RadMap control. The RadMap control has an included ToolTip when you hover over a pin. It dynamically renderes the styles for it, and a lot of them are inline. The only thing I need to do is increase the width on 2 divs that are generated by Telerik's Web Resources. One of them only has one class and no ID, and the other has multiple classes. Keep in mind each pin has these 2 divs, so they appear multiple times in the rendered DOM.
Here's the first div:

```
<div class="k-animation-container" style="left: 714px; top: 193.12px; width: 255px; height: 234px; overflow: visible; padding-right: 4px; padding-bottom: 4px; padding-left: 4px; margin-left: -4px; display: block; position: absolute; z-index: 10002; box-sizing: content-box;">
```

And here's the second (it's the child of the first):

```
<div class="k-widget k-tooltip k-popup k-group k-reset RadMap RadMap_Default k-state-border-up" role="tooltip" style="display: block; position: absolute; opacity: 1;" data-role="popup"><div class="k-tooltip-content">
```

I've tried using CSS with a stronger selector, but the styles don't even appear as overridden in Page Inspector. I also tried using jquery's addClass function and .attr('id', 'myCustomId');. Neither seems to work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You should access the marker tooltip widget (it is a Kendo Tooltip) and set its properties (e.g., width, height, animation, whatever) as desired.

http://www.telerik.com/forums/marker-tooltip-show-on-load#7svmjCUvskKO5Nr94p8svw is an example:

**attach to the load event**

```
<ClientEvents OnLoad="map_load"/>
```

**loop through the markers, access their tooltips and set properties**

```
function map_load(sender, args) {
           map = sender.get_kendoWidget();
           //If we have items, we'll show our item tooltip
           if (map.markers.items.length > 0) {
               map.markers.items[0].tooltip...... //set properties               
           }
       }
```